# Voltage drop across TPS259631DDAR when drawing current

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, power-electronics

I'm building a powerbank and I'm using an E-Fuse IC for the battery protection (specifically, the TPS259631DDAR). As soon as I start drawing any current the voltage drops from 4.1v to 3.4v. The more current I draw, the more the voltage drops. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've gone through the datasheet multiple times but nothing makes sense at this point. I'll provide my schematic and PCB design for you to have a more detailed look at.
[image: The schematic]
[image: The PCB]
I'll be more than happy to provide anything else that you may require to help me out, here.
Thank you so much!

Comment: How much currrent are you drawing when you measure 3.4 V?  Your traces are pretty small for power rails.

Comment: I'm drawing 500mA when I measure 3.4v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The efuse on resistance is 89 mOhm.  Your traces look pretty small.  If they were 10 mil traces on 0.5 oz copper, and a total of 3" long that would add an additional 0.26 ohms, for about 0.35 ohms total.  That would give you your 0.7 V drop at a current of 2 A.  However, you have to figure out your actual trace resistance and load current to see if it makes sense.  There's a trace resistance calculator [here.](https://www.omnicalculator.com/other/pcb-trace-resistance)

Comment: I calculated my trace resistance to be 0.1 ohm for a total resistance of 0.19 ohm. I measure the 0.7v voltage drop when drawing 500mA. That would amount to a voltage drop of just 0.08v. This is way lower than what I'm seeing

Comment: OK, get a multimeter and start measuring the drops.  From input to eFuse, across the eFuse, eFuse to next component, etc.  then tell us where the unexpected drop is coming from.

Comment: Ok, I've measured the voltage drops between the input and the eFuse, across the eFuse, eFuse to the next component (which is a boost converter), and I can confirm that the voltage drop is across the eFuse IC.

Comment: OK, good find.  Check R5 to be sure it's the correct value.  Also, how did you solder the part to the board? Are you sure the metal pad on the bottom of the IC is well soldered to the board?

Comment: Yup, found the reason. R5 was supposed to be a 450 ohm resistor. I had mistakenly soldered on a 1.82k ohm resistor which set the current limit to about 500mA, hence the voltage drop. I have now replaced the resistor and it works flawlessly. Thank you for all your help! I'll reach out again, if I have a problem! :)